# Prevent late static binding with static variable access from parent function

Tags: php, late-static-binding

Given the following class hierarchy:

```
class ParentClass {
    private static $_test;

    public function returnTest() {
        return static::$_test;
    }
}
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    // intentionally left blank
}
$child = new ChildClass();
echo $child->returnTest();
```

The output generated is the following error message:
`Fatal error: Cannot access property ChildClass::$_test`
Is there a way to prevent late static binding from happening? Since I am calling a function of a parent class that is not overwritten, I feel like I should be allowed to do something like the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `return self::$_test` instead of `return static::$_test`.

This insures that you access the field `$_test` of  the class where `returnTest` is defined.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php for reference.

Comment: What is the difference between calling ParentClass::$_test like suggested by Mathieu Imbert and calling self::$_test?

Comment: Technically, none: the result is the same. I guess it's a matter of taste, whether you want to explicitly repeat the class name or not. BTW, edited my answer with a link to the PHP documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling a static property from an instantiated class. Just use the name of the class:

```
return static::$_test;
```